# Making labels in array change backcolor on click using C# in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, arrays, label

How can I change the BackColor of a label in an array when I click on it? Since there are multiple elements, I cannot manually activate each event for each individual label.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
        {
            board[i] = new Label();
            board[i].Parent = pictureBox1;
            board[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            board[i].Name = "label" + i;
            board[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
            //set size of labels
            board[i].Size = new Size(30, 30);
            //initialize click event handler
            this.board[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.labelClick);

        }

private void labelClick (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Label i in board)
            {
                if (iteration % 2 == 0)
                {
                    i.BackColor = Color.Black;
                    iteration++;
                }
                else if(iteration % 2 == 1)
                {
                    i.BackColor = Color.White;
                    iteration++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can handle this. One way is to wire each Labels Click event up to the same event:

```
this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label_Click);
this.label2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label_Click);
this.label3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label_Click);
```

In the label_Click event you can set the BackColor of each label OR just the one you clicked on.

```
// This will set each label's BackColor to Red.
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Label label in labelArray)
    {
        label.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}

// This will set just the clicked on Label's BackColor to Red.
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label label = sender as Label;
    if (label != null)
    {
        label.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1925801 Based on your edit history it looks like you may have resolved your issue. I'm not clear however on what your target outcome was. Did you want to have the form load with all Transparent labels, then when the user clicks on any label, all the labels would turn into a checker board pattern?

Comment: Issue is resolved. I had stuff with my for loop that should not have been there (not pictured). Also did not know that transparent really meant the backcolor of the parent element. As a result I got rid of the picturebox which was the background image and instead I set the background image of the form itself and then the labels to backcolor = transparent and got my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var labels = new[] 
{
    // labels here
};

foreach (var label in labels)
{
    label.Click += (sender, args) =>
       {
           var lbl = sender as Label;
           Debug.Assert(lbl != null);
           lbl.BackColour = Colors.Pink;
       };
}
```